# Can't install client certificate on different device?

Tags: firefox, apache-http-server, ssl, certificate, client-certificate

I setup a simple Apache 2 server and enabled a secure SSL connection. I used my own self-signed Root-CA-Certificate to create a Sub-CA and used that one to create the server certificate that is installed on the Apache server.

Now I want to enable client authentication, so that a website is only accessible when the user provides a valid certificate. So i enabled the SSLVerify option on the server and accessing the HTTPS connection is now not possible without a user certificate.

I used my Sub-CA certificate to create a user certificate. I am using openssl on a ubuntu VM, so I copied the file to my native Windows 10 and tried to install the user certificate in my Firefox Browser on the native platform. However, the installation failed, stating I do not own the private key that is associated with the certificate. I troubleshooted a bit and it turns out, installing a certificate that was created on a different machine is a problem. I did not find a solution for this problem however.

Is there any way to install this user certificate on my brwoser on my Windows 10 machine without having to generate a new certificate file?

Comment: I just tried to install the client certificate in Firefox on the VM where the certificate was created. That shows the same error. So I don't know what I'm supposed to do. The exact error string is "This personal certificate can’t be installed because you do not own the corresponding private key which was created when the certificate was requested." I did create the public/private key pair myself so I don't know what I have to do to convince Firefox I do own them.

Comment: How did you create them, and how did you convert them into a file that'd be importable into Firefox?

Comment: @user1686 I am new to this stuff. I used this tutorial: https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/index.html

I created pem files for the certificate and tried to import that into Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox does not support importing private keys from "PEM" files.

When you ask it to import a certificate from a PEM or DER file, it'll import *only* the certificate, not any private keys that might be in the file. Instead, it expects to associate the certificate with an "unbound" private key that it already has (i.e. one that was previously generated using the obsolete `<keygen>` tag).

If you have a certificate with an externally generated private key, you need to export both to a .p12 file in the PKCS#12 format (aka PFX, just like the .pfx files used by Windows), e.g. using `openssl pkcs12 -export`.

Comment: Thanks, I exported the certificate with the key in the p12 format and Firefox accepted it. Now however, the Apache server doesn't seem to accept it... But that's a different problem